# cost of developing and running a GPS application

Tags: mobile

i am currently undergoing the branding of a place that is in the outskirts of a major city. the situation at hand is that the place is unknown and not easy to get around, so my associates and i have planned to develop a gps application with specifics eg safari lodges, conference venues of this area and make it possible for people to download it onto their smartphones (nokia,iphone and black berry) and be able to navigate their way around.

the issue is how much would it cost to develop such an application and run it?

need an answer ASAP. thanks a mil.

Comment: "I have no idea what I want, but how much does it cost? Oh, and it's needed ASAP." - You must be a manager of some kind, maybe even a CEO :)

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question could be 1000$, but it could be 100.000$ as well. There are so many details to a project like this that must be taken into account that it is almost impossible to answer your question more precisely.

To give an example - consider details like (but not only):

- who will supply the necessary content
- does the content need to be updated on a regular basis -> CMS
- should the app navigate the user around in turn-by-turn style or should it be more like an interactive map

These three details alone would make a huge difference. So, the best thing you can do is contact a company or a freelance developer, brief him precisely on the matter and see how much it'll cost you.